# Mistake by Sean Carroll on EPR paradox for layman?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, popular-science

In his book *From Eternity to Here*, Sean Carroll uses a system consisting of a cat (Miss Kitty) and a dog (Mr. Dog) behaving as quantum objects to introduce the EPR paradox. The cat and dog are initially in the following entangled state:

$$(\text{cat under the table},\text{dog in living room}) + (\text{cat on the sofa},\text{dog in the yard}).$$

He then imagines that the state evolves smoothly to the following state, since the dog escapes from the yard to planet Mars:

$$(\text{cat under the table},\text{dog in living room}) + (\text{cat on the sofa},\text{dog on planet Mars}).$$

It is then said that an observer on Mars (Billy) sees the dog and that we now have a 100 percent chance of observing the cat to be on the sofa, which is all fine. What bothers me is what he writes after:

> But so what? We don’t actually know that Billy did any such observation–for all we know, if we looked for Mr. Dog we would find him in the living room.

In the living room? Why? The dog is on Mars! This a mistake or what?

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: I don't read it as I think you are reading it - I read it as saying that though the dog has 0% chance of being found in the living room (since Billy observed the dog on Mars), *we don't know that* until, e.g., Billy's message from Mars, traveling at the speed of light, arrives here.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri you are right, I had interpreted iit differently, it is a translation problem.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no mistake. Carroll's point doesn't even depend on the fact that this is an entangled state, and you would get the same if you started off with some classical probability mixture of the same form,
$$(\text{cat under the table},\text{dog in living room}) + (\text{cat on the sofa},\text{dog in the yard}).$$
For this kind of distribution **if** the dog is in the yard, then it will escape to the planet Mars. However, we do not know for certain that it starts off in the yard: it could well start off in the living room, and in that case it will not go to Mars.

Thus, if we assume an even 50-50 split in the original probabilities, then regardless of where the dog might or might not go if the yard door is broken, there will be a 50% chance that we'll see it in the living room.

Similarly, **if** the dog is observed on Mars, **and** that fact gets communicated to us, then we can be certain that the cat will be on the sofa, but we have no guarantee that the dog will be observed on Mars (because 50% of the time it won't make it there), so until and unless we hear from Billy with the observation, we have no such certainty.

Comment: That makes sense, but Carroll writes that without the information from Billy we **would** find Mr. Dog in the living room if we looked for it, as if it was 100% sure.  Shouldn't he have written that as far as we know we **could** find Mr. Dog in the living room instead?

Comment: No, that is a misreading of the text as you have quoted it, particularly regarding the function of the phrase "for all we know".